# Does the Reflections package caches resources

Tags: reflection, classpath, reflections

I am using the [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) package to scan some files in my classpath. The code below is run at regular intervals. Basically i am retriving all xml files within a folder 'tmp' in the classpath. This code is being run from a web application.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("tmp", new ResourcesScanner());
Set<String> xmls = reflections.getResources(Pattern.compile(".*\\.xml"));
```

When i add another xml file in the services folder it gets read. However, when i update any of those xml files, the update is NOT reflected. Is there some kind of caching going on there? If yes, is there anyway to avoid the same?

Answer (score 1):

No, Reflections does not cache resources. It simply scans and creates a Store object - actually a multimap of Strings.

Reading / retrieving the resources on runtime is done based on their names (via Store) and uses the configured classloader (which defaults to the context class loader)